# IOS, handler push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification

there is any way to handler Push notification that came in to the device when he is not in the app (background) ?

let say my apns send msg: "hello world" 
I want to change the message (not by the server, by my app) before the device display the push notification when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do this using [Silent Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1), since you're unable to change the message when using *normal* push notifications (the OS will display the message when it is received).

When you send a silent push, you can just handle it in your app delegate then schedule a local notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler {

    NSDictionary *apsPayload = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    if ([userInfo[@"content-available"] boolValue] /* silent push */) {
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.alertBody = @"Hello Local World!";
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this. You can get a silent push notification. When you get the notification, alter it as you wish, then schedule a local notification with the alert that you'd like to display. Full disclosure, I've not actually tried this.